# How can I avoid words wrapping in my table <td> cells?

Tags: html, css

I have a table that is too big for my page. What I wanted was to get scroll bars but what happens is the words in a `<td>` wrap around onto the next line. Is there a way I can stop the words wrapping so that the table gets big and the scroll bars appear?

Note I already enclosed my table in a `overflow-x: auto` div.

Comment: Please have a look at this [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: [`white-space:nowrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) should suffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it with css you would use:

```
 white-space: nowrap;
```

This forces it to stay on one line.

Ex: http://jsbin.com/EsenUCI/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 2):

You could add the nowrap flag to your td tag.  There is probably a css version (which would be a more modern way to do it)

eg:

```
<td nowrap>text text text</td>
```